# PostgreSQL save table columns results into variables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, select-into

I have this function:

```
DECLARE 
    _first_name text;
    _last_name  text;
BEGIN
SELECT 
    emp.first_name INTO _first_name,
    emp.last_name INTO _last_name,
FROM employee emp LIMIT 1
END;
```

(I simplified the function to eliminate the information noise)

As you can see, i can get only 1 result because of 'LIMIT'. So i need to store this 2 columns into my 2 variables. But i am getting an error like '**INTO specified more than once**'. How to bypass this, any ideas?

Comment: `INTO` is a clause and used once with multiple variables.  The error message seems quite clear, which is why I'm belatedly voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `INTO` once as follows:

```
SELECT 
    emp.first_name, emp.last_name INTO _first_name, _last_name
FROM employee emp LIMIT 1
```

Columns and variables must be in the same sequence respectively.